# Try to get person image

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm testing this microsoft cognitive service and this is awsome!
By now I'm developing a simple WPF GUI to manage groups and person.
I can careate and retreive groups and its persons but I cant get the images I've already uploaded.
I'm using this https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395240 function to get the face/image but the only response is the persistedFaceId.
Is there a way to retreive the person's images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Face API does not provide such a feature, unfortunately.  Your application would need to maintain this information.